# 301 and HTTPS redirect to root via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https, http-status-code-301

I moved domain from `http` to `https`. And currently all `http` urls are redirected to `https`.
But there are some broken links from old urls such as `http://domain.tld/url-link-broken` and I would like to redirect them to the root domain.
The problem is that currently *`http://domain.tld/url-link-broken`* redirects to *`https://domain.tld/url-link-broken`* 
How can I change this via htaccess so that **if url is broken** it would not only redirect to https but also to the root?

Comment: this called mix content issue

Answer (score 0):

**Check following things first**

- Your console gives any error there regarding resources
- Check do you have static links in menu or anywhere else
- Check your home_url and site_url in admin

**Solution**

- Using Plugin:
  Please Take Backup of database before proceed

  https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

For More Information :

https://managewp.com/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings